# Java how to access another ArrayList from another class?

Tags: java, arraylist

I tried the getter method ( create a getter method is this class and return the object so you can use it in another class) but when I run it's just an empty ArrayList

In this example I have the user to input the code (1, 2 ,3 , ...) and a random name then store that value in an ArrayList list but when I create an instance of that class and use the getList() method it return an empty ArrayList.
This is the code:

SubTestSite1

```
package testsite;

public class SubTestSite1 {

private int id;
private String name;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getId() + "   " + this.getName()+"    ";
}

public SubTestSite1() {
}

public SubTestSite1(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

SubTestSite2

```
package testsite;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class SubTestSite2 {
Hashtable hash = new Hashtable(100);
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(100);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    

public ArrayList getList() {
    return list;
}

public void add() {
    int id;
    String name, choice = null, customer;
    do {
        System.out.print("enter id: ");
        id = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.print("enter name: ");
        name = sc.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();
        SubTestSite1 sts1 = new SubTestSite1(id, name);
        list.add(sts1);
        System.out.println("Continue? Y/N");
        choice = sc.nextLine();
    } while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    System.out.print("Customer name: ");
    customer = sc.nextLine();
    hash.put(customer, list);
    SubTestSite3 sts3 = new SubTestSite3();
    sts3.displayOrder(this.hash, customer);
}
}
```

SubTestSite3

```
package testsite;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SubTestSite3 {

public void displayOrder(Hashtable hash, String name) {
    SubTestSite2 sts2 = new SubTestSite2();
    System.out.println(sts2.getList());

}
}
```

The main

```
package testsite;

public class TestSite {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SubTestSite2 sts2 = new SubTestSite2();
    sts2.add();
}
}
```

Don't mind the Hashtable though, I just wanna play around with it :P
Thanks!

Comment: Did you call `add` at all on `sts2`?

Comment: means you havent add anything to it. Debugging helpes.

Comment: But I thought I was returning the list AFTER  those values was added right? So in theory the list that I get in Site3 is suppose to be the current one with values in it.

Comment: It seems that SubTestSite2.add has never been called and SubTestSite2.list has never been changed according to the code you show.

Comment: I added the `static` keyword before the initialization of ArrayList and it works....I'm still confused though ;_;

Comment: Where do you create SubTestSite3 object?  Do you have the code for your main method? Do you know the difference between static and instance fields?

Comment: Do not use static for simply accessing the object value. It can create unexpected problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see your `main` method, so I'm guessing that you are creating a `SubTestSite2` object from `main` and calling `add()` on it there. Let's call that object `mainsts` for clarity. If this is the case, you add the items to mainsts's list, then create a new `SubTestSite2` object, `sts2`, and attempt to read `sts2's` list, not `mainsts's`. Since you did not declare the ArrayList as static, each object, mainsts and sts2 in this case, has its own list, so the list for sts2 would indeed be empty, but mainsts's would not be.

When you declared the `ArrayList` as `static`, you made it into a class variable rather than an instance variable. As 'static', all objects that use that class will use that variable. In other words, mainsts and sts2 here would share the same list. If you want this, I would say access the list directly through the class with SubTestSite2.list

Comment: Oh I forgot but yeah it was exactly like you said I initialize the SubTestSite2 and call the add() method and that's it

Comment: If i use SubTestSite2.list then must I declare the ArrayList as `static` ?

Comment: Accessing a variable directly through the class when it isn't static is unstable. I'm guessing the program won't know what version of the variable to use and will give you an error.